# usb_libusb10.h(72): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cb'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, libusb

I am getting the following error even though it seems there are no syntax errors.
**usb_libusb10.h(72): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cb'**

The line where the error is generating is given below-

**fnusb_iso_cb cb;**

I also tried to highlighted this line by using "**" in the code. 
Following is the code I am using.

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <afxwin.h>

#include "libfreenect.h"
#include <libusb.h>

// There are a few rules: PKTS_PER_XFER * NUM_XFERS <= 1000, PKTS_PER_XFER % 8 == 0.
#if defined(__APPLE__)
  #define DEPTH_PKTBUF 2048
  #define VIDEO_PKTBUF 2048

  #define PKTS_PER_XFER 128
  #define NUM_XFERS 4
#else
  #define DEPTH_PKTBUF 1920
  #define VIDEO_PKTBUF 1920

  #if defined(_WIN32)
    #define PKTS_PER_XFER 32
    #define NUM_XFERS 8
  #else
    #define PKTS_PER_XFER 16
    #define NUM_XFERS 16
  #endif
#endif

typedef struct {
    libusb_context *ctx;
    int should_free_ctx;
} fnusb_ctx;

typedef struct {
    freenect_device *parent; //so we can go up from the libusb userdata
    libusb_device_handle *dev;
    int device_dead; // set to 1 when the underlying libusb_device_handle vanishes (ie, Kinect was unplugged)
    int VID;
    int PID;
} fnusb_dev;

typedef struct {
    fnusb_dev *parent; //so we can go up from the libusb userdata
    struct libusb_transfer **xfers;
    uint8_t *buffer;
    **fnusb_iso_cb cb;**
    int num_xfers;
    int pkts;
    int len;
    int dead;
    int dead_xfers;
} fnusb_isoc_stream;

int fnusb_num_devices(fnusb_ctx *ctx);
int fnusb_list_device_attributes(fnusb_ctx *ctx, struct freenect_device_attributes** attribute_list);

int fnusb_init(fnusb_ctx *ctx, freenect_usb_context *usb_ctx);
int fnusb_shutdown(fnusb_ctx *ctx);
int fnusb_process_events(fnusb_ctx *ctx);
int fnusb_process_events_timeout(fnusb_ctx *ctx, struct timeval* timeout);

int fnusb_open_subdevices(freenect_device *dev, int index);
int fnusb_close_subdevices(freenect_device *dev);

int fnusb_start_iso(fnusb_dev *dev, fnusb_isoc_stream *strm, fnusb_iso_cb cb, unsigned char endpoint, int xfers, int pkts, int len);
int fnusb_stop_iso(fnusb_dev *dev, fnusb_isoc_stream *strm);
int fnusb_get_max_iso_packet_size(fnusb_dev *dev, unsigned char endpoint, int default_size);

int fnusb_control(fnusb_dev *dev, uint8_t bmRequestType, uint8_t bRequest, uint16_t wValue, uint16_t wIndex, uint8_t *data, uint16_t wLength);
int fnusb_bulk(fnusb_dev *dev, uint8_t endpoint, uint8_t *data, int len, int *transferred);
int fnusb_num_interfaces(fnusb_dev *dev);
```

Comment: Where is `fnusb_iso_cb` defined?

Comment: I think its defined under the typedef struct of "fnusb_isoc_stream".However,I have found this header file from the libfreenect source files.Didnt change anything at all inside the code!

Comment: No, that's not the definition. In VS, right click on it and `Go To Definition`. Search for `C2146`, there are thousands of helpful answers out there..